# iOS Custom TableView With Images and Checkmarks

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to duplicate whats in the link provided. I'm trying to display a Tableview with images that can by checked for an IOS application. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong to where its not showing the images. I made sure I added the images to the assets folder and called them correctly in my ViewController file. Here is the code for my file:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var myText: UILabel!
}

class RmMatchingViewControllor : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{ //
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var labelData = ["Social Drinking", "Clean Freak", " Do you Cook", "Enjoy Movies", "Listen to Music", "Enjoy Sports","Perefer temperature cold", "Non smoking"]
    var imageData = ["Beer", "Clean", "cooking", "movies", "Music","NFL","roomTemp", "Smoking"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomCell //check this spot if program doesnt run
        cell.myText?.text = self.labelData[indexPath.row]
        cell.myImage?.image = UIImage(named:self.imageData[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelData.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath){
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            } else{
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the picture of the ViewControllor]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO59w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcoYO.png)

Comment: Change `cell.myImage?.image` to `cell.myImage.image`.

Comment: Check if `UIImage(named:self.imageData[indexPath.row])` is nil to see if the problem is on loading the image

Comment: Where is the link you talking about?

Comment: this is the link https://www.journaldev.com/14180/ios-custom-tableview-images-checkmarks

Comment: Is it showing the text? maybe add a screenshot of your current output in the simulator

Comment: Did you remember to connect the `myImage` outlet?

Comment: I made sure to reference the myImage outlet and still nothing displayed

Comment: I post the video, I hope this could help you https://www.dropbox.com/s/382avifid37ri4l/Screen%20Recording.mov?dl=0

Comment: I looked at the video and I still got the same results. I'm starting to think I may have done something wrong with the viewControllor

Answer (score 0):

@Tyrek Clarke Try adding a breakpoint at `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and see whether it's being called or assigning the image properly. You can normally check the output of a UIImage. I've tried using the same code and am able to produce a result. (intended to miss a few images)

[image: Result]

Things to look out for:

- Your table view delegate and data source are connected
- Your cell reuse identifier should be the same as what you've written in code
- Make sure your IBOutlets are attached
- Check the image name (Make sure there's no difference)

Answer (score 0):

[image]var slotCellArray : [SlotCell] = SlotCell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SlotObjectArray.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell
     = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SlotCell_id", for: indexPath) as! SlotCell

    cell.lbl_slot_details.text = SlotObjectArray[indexPath.row].Time

    if (SlotObjectArray[indexPath.row].Available_Status as? Bool)! {

       cell.btn_slot_status_out.setTitle(" ", for: .normal)

    } else {

         cell.btn_slot_status_out.setTitle("✔️", for: .normal)
    }
    cell.btn_slot_status_out.tag = indexPath.row


    self.slotCellArray.append(cell)

    return cell




}


@IBAction func btn_slot_status_act(_ sender: UIButton) {

if sender.titleLabel?.text == "✔️"
{
         SlotObjectArray[sender.tag].Available_Status = true

    for i in 0..<selectedSlots.count {
      print(i)
        if let slotSelected = selectedSlots[i] as? AnyObject {

            if let SlotId = slotSelected["slot_id"] as? String {

                if SlotId == SlotObjectArray[sender.tag].id {
                    selectedSlots.remove(at: i)
                    break
                }

            }

        }

    }



    print(selectedSlots)

} else {

      SlotObjectArray[sender.tag].Available_Status = false
    let slot = ["Slot_id":SlotObjectArray[sender.tag].id,"Selected_time":SlotObjectArray[sender.tag].Time,"Booking_date":txt_date.text!]

    selectedSlots.append(slot as AnyObject)


     print(selectedSlots)
    }
   tbl_slots_list.reloadData()

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```